Where should i bind and unbind my service in jetpack compose?
I have foreground service in my app, that contains some values i want to share with ui for example speed and total.
Im using extend Binder class method from android documentation link
These values are being updated in service during installation process, and i need them in SetupScreen for that time only. So i think bind service should be called after user launch installation process button and start service.
My problem is that i dont know where should i put bind/unbind code logic, i dont need to bind it on app start so i havent added it to MainActivity
Also unbind should be called the same context it was binded. Where should i put that code if my app is running like MainActivity -> BottomNavigation (composable function) -> SetupScreen (composable function) and i need to bind it in that setup screen?
Its working when i create companion object in main activity and call MainActivity bind and unbind in service itself, but its creating leak
